# how to return bool as json?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I want to write a extension method that return bool value as json as follow:

```
public static string ToJson(this bool value)
    {
      var data = new { Succed = value };
      return new 
      Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
    }
```

I need return responce as:

```
"Succed":True
```

or:

```
"Succed":"True"
```

But it returns :

```
"{\"Succed\":true}"
```

How can I do for fix this..??

Comment: Only the last example is valid JSON.  JSON is wrapped in `{}` and it's "true" is a literal, all lower-case `true`.

Comment: but it's string.I need json format as {"Succed":true}

Comment: don't serialize it yourself, prepare your return object and let web api deal with serializing it. You will end up with the response serialized twice if you go ahead with that extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static string ToJson(this bool value)
{
     var data = new { Succed = value };
     return data;
}
```